# Page Redirecting and storing OpenID user information

Tags: php, redirect, openid

I am currently implementing [lightopenid](https://gitorious.org/lightopenid). It is partly working but I am having difficulties redirecting users while keeping credentials. The example below has the user login through google and then supposedly redirect to a user access page where it displays their name. Nothing is being displayed in useraccess.php. How can I redirect the user with their credentials from openID properly

login.php

```
<?php
# Logging in with Google accounts requires setting special identity, so this example shows how to do it.
session_start();
require 'openid.php';

try {

    $openid = new LightOpenID('http://mydomain.com');                           // akshat - declared an object of class lightopenid.. this is listed in openid.php
    if(!$openid->mode) {

        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {

            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=mydomain.com'; //this can be changed as you know...      

            $openid->required = array('namePerson/friendly', 'contact/email' , 'contact/country/home', 'namePerson/first', 'pref/language', 'namePerson/last'); // akshat - line added by me from after reading from the net....

            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());    
        }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//change to jquery so it is compatible with cross browsers
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("lform").submit();
}
</script>
<form name="form" id="lform" action="?login" method="post"> </form>
<?php
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication for Your Domain !';
    } else {                                                // FETCH USER INFO HERE
                $fname = $openid->ret_fname();              // fetching user first name...
        $lname = $openid->ret_lname();                  // fetching user last name...
        $email = $openid->ret_email();                  // fetching user email...
        $lang = $openid->ret_lang();                    // fetching user language...
                session_start();

                // use it as required. I set them in session !
                $_SESSION['admin']['emailID'] = $email;          //put email id in session.
                $_SESSION['admin']['fname'] = $fname;            //put first name also in session.
                $_SESSION['admin']['lname'] = $lname;            //put last name also in session.

                header("Location: www.example.com/useraccess.php");              // Go back to the calling application !

    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

useraccess.php

```
<?php

session_start();

echo 'User is: ' . $fname . ' ' . $lname;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in useraccess.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo 'User is: ' . $_SESSION['admin']['fname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['admin']['lname'];
?>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you! is there away to redirect user to login page if they are not logged in?

Comment: You wrote the code that after login user will redirect to useraccess.php

Comment: yes, i mean if someone type in the browser a url: `mydomain.com/useraccess.php` I want them to be redirected to `mydomain.com/login.php`if there are not logged in

Comment: make a condition to check session is set or not.
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['admin']['fname']) && isset($_SESSION['admin']['lname']) && isset($_SESSION['admin']['emailID']) ) {
 echo 'User is: ' . $_SESSION['admin']['fname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['admin']['lname'];
}else{
 header("Location: www.example.com/login.php");
}
?>condition to check session is set or not.

Comment: Something like `if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']['fname']))` or need to be more general?

Comment: You can store user id in session & check that only like if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']['userid']))

Comment: That is exactly what I need but not sure since 'userid' is not defined in my code. I placed line `if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']['userid']))` but it is redirecting back to login page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40797/discussion-between-rohit-and-codelover1985)